# how can i tell to chrome to inspect an element in my js function?

Tags: javascript, inspect

Suppose we have a function like this:

```
function showProps(el){
    inspect(el);
}
```

what is the solution for this that when we call this function the chrome open the inspecting window and locate the el element?

In the chrome console when used inspect(document.body) it does what we want and opens the inspecting section and select the body element.
but when we run in my function, it says the inspect() method is undefined and unknown.

Comment: no, you can't do anything like that in chrome ... or any browser - the `inspect` function in the console is a convenience only available in the console

Comment: If you are willing to use an extension - Does this answer your question? [Invoke the inspect() function of DevTools from within a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222258/invoke-the-inspect-function-of-devtools-from-within-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for reply. can extensions communicate with javascript codes?

Comment: Some [reading material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-from-an-extension/9517879#9517879) about this -  FYI: I, myself, have little to no experience with developing extensions for Chrome

Comment: @DarkBee tnx for reply.

Answer (score 0):

The various commands available in the devtools console are not available to normal scripts running in the page. It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think there's any API available from normal scripts that would let code open the devtools window and inspect an element.

As a poor workaround, if you have an element that's difficult to select with the mouse etc., you could have your code do `console.log(theElement)` and then in the console you can right-click the element display and choose "Reveal in Elements panel". But that's not the same thing of course.

If you're willing to use an extension, [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222258/invoke-the-inspect-function-of-devtools-from-within-a-chrome-extension) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ii am developing a web designer and just want to let the designer to edit the selected element's styles.  and the chrome's style editor is very useful to this. so decided to use it by an API such inspect(). but seems there is no way to call it from the js.  hey! can we make an extension which can do a command from the javascript function caller?   i mean can i develop an extension to do what i want?

Comment: I mean can extensions communicate  with javascript codes?

Comment: @kp64 - I've never written a Chrome extension, but I'm fairly sure that yes, they can expose functions pages can call.